# Linear transformation from the set of continuous functions $C([0,1])$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\varepsilon : C([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be a mapping $$f\mapsto (f(0), f(1))$$ show that $\varepsilon$ is a linear transformation from the set of continuous functions $C([0,1])$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$.

For $\varepsilon$ to be linear transformation it would need to satisfy $\varepsilon(x+y) = \varepsilon(x) + \varepsilon(y)$ and $\varepsilon(cx) = c\varepsilon(x)$. However, I'm not sure how to approach this since we're not given any excplicit function to show this? Any hints would be appreciated...

Comment: Why do you say it a not an explicit function?

Comment: Here, rather than $x,y$, the vectors in $C([0,1])$ would perhaps be better represented as variables $f,g$.  Remember what the domain vector space is and how vector addition and scalar multiplication are defined there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just the definition of function addition and multiplacation of function by a scalar. In $C([0,1])$ functions have both same domain and codomain, so you have permission for addition and scalar multiplication.
$\epsilon(f+g)=((f+g)(0),(f+g)(1))=?$
$\epsilon(cf)=((cf)(0),(cf)(1))=?$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$